# Do not capture optional html tag in regex

Tags: regex

I want to parse the names of the teams. But as you can see the in the picture below the last two lines don't have `<a>` tag. My regex code selects also the closing tag of `<a>`. How to avoid this?

**HTML**

```
<td class="team2"><a class="black" href="/team/test/">Test team</a></td>
<td class="team3"><a class="black" href="/team/test/">Opponent team</a></td>
<td class="team2">Test team</td>
<td class="team3">Opponent Team</td>
```

**Regex**

```
<td class="team\d">(<a class="black" href=".+">)?(.+)(<\/a>)?<\/td>
```

[image]

Comment: Tip for life: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use a parser depending on the language you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original expression is great, just missing a (`?`), which we would add that and slightly simplify it to:

```
<td(.+?)>(<a(.+?)>)?(.+?)(<\/a>)?<\/td>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cnzj4K/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

```js
const regex = /<td(.+?)>(<a(.+?)>)?(.+?)(<\/a>)?<\/td>/gm;
const str = `<td class="team2"><a class="black" href="/team/test/">Tést team</a></td>
<td class="team3"><a class="black" href="/team/test/">opponent team</a></td>
<td class="team2">test team</td>
<td class="team3">my  team</td>`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```